# PYTHON- Equivalencia de Tipos

Tags: python, estructuras-de-datos

Soy nuevo en programando en python y tengo una duda acerca del lenguaje ¿Que tecnica de equivalencia de tipos utiliza, nominal o estructural? Me gustaria saber asi logro comprender con mayor profundidad el funcionamiento del lenguaje.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Python es un lenguaje de tipado dinámico. Es decir, las variables no tienen tipo, son los datos quienes tienen tipo. Y una variable puede referirse a diferentes datos (de diferentes tipos) en diferentes momentos del programa, por lo que no es posible conocer el tipo de la variable en tiempo de ejecución. En cierto sentido podría decirse que es tipado estructural, aunque eso depende de qué estructura de datos concreta estés considerando. Por ejemplo, así sería en tuplas o listas en las que cada elemento puede ser de un tipo (y por tanto la posición te diría el tipo).

Comment: Pero todo es demasiado dinámico, ya que más adelante la lista podría cambiar los valores que contiene y eso "rompería" el supuesto tipado estructural. Podría decirse que tiene ambos, según de qué estructura de datos hablemos (las clases por ejemplo las veo más nominales y las tuplas más estructurales). Pero en realidad, creo que la respuesta correcta sería **ninguno de los dos**. El tipado es dinámico y por tanto puede variar en el tiempo.

Comment: No sé si mis comentarios tienen algún sentido para tí. No soy especialista en teoría de tipos. Pero si tienes dudas menos "abstractas" :-) pregunta de nuevo!

Answer (score 2):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, los tipos de python son *"estructurales"*. No tienen tipado fuerte, por lo que no es posible establecer un sistema de tipos completo donde se definan "clases de tipos" (*typeclasses*). Pero sí que es posible definir lo que se conocen como *"protocolos"* que serían algo así como una lista de métodos que debe tener un grupo de objetos para considerarlo de la misma clase.

Por ejemplo, de un *objeto fichero* se espera que tenga, por lo menos, los métodos `read()` y `write(s)`. Cualquier objeto con estos dos métodos se comporta como un objeto `file` y, por tanto, se puede hacer pasar por fichero en cualquier sitio (con salvedades). Este funcionamiento se conoce como *duck typing*: "si anda como un pato y grazna como un pato, entonces es un pato".

En realidad, el protocolo `file` es más complejo, con métodos `close`, `seek`,... de texto, bytes, etc. La librería estándar define varias *clases abstractas* ([ABC - Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class)) que *determinan los métodos que debe implementar un objeto para pertenecer a una clase tipo*. Por ejemplo, [IOBase](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html#io.IOBase) sería el ancestro de todos los objetos ficheros. De él se derivan las clases `RawIOBase`, `BufferedIOBase` y `TextIOBase`. Ésta última sería la correspondiente a los ficheros de texto, propiamente hablando.

Pero hay muchas más clases abstractas. Las más interesantes:

- Tipos numéricos en el módulo [numbers](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/numbers.html)
- *Streams* en el módulo [io](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html)
- Colecciones en el módulo [collections](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.abc.html): `Iterable`, `Iterator`, `Sequence`, `Set`, `Mapping`, `Generator`, ...

Ejemplo de *Iterables* son `list`, `str`, `dict` o `tuple`. *Sequences* serían `list`, `str` y `tuple`. El tipo `dict` funciona también como *Sequence*, pero se considera más apropiado considerarlo *Mapping*, aunque no hay nada que lo fije como tal.

Para concluir, una aclaración: en python, clase y tipo son la misma cosa. El modo correcto para saber de qué tipo es un objeto es averiguando de qué clase deriva usando `isinstance`. Lo mismo, para saber si un tipo es subtipo de otro se usa `issubclass`.

Por ejemplo, *Iterable* sería un objeto con un método `__iter__`. En este caso es sencillo chequear la existencia de este método usando la función `hasattr`. Pero resultaría más complicado si fueran muchos los métodos a chequear. Mejor hacerlo así:

```
In [1]: from collections.abc import Iterable                                                                            

In [2]: isinstance([1,2,3], Iterable)                                                                                   
Out[2]: True

In [3]: isinstance(1, Iterable)                                                                                         
Out[3]: False

In [4]: class C: 
   ...:     def __iter__(self): 
   ...:         return None 
   ...:                                                                                                                 

In [5]: issubclass(C, Iterable)                                                                                         
Out[5]: True
```

Hay que observar que el método `__iter__` de la clase devuelve `None`, que no corresponde con el objeto iterador que se espera de este método. No habría forma de saber si funciona realmente como iterable hasta el momento de ejecutarse, momento en que daría error. Afortunadamente, hay herramientas de desarrollo que ayudan a prevenir estos fallos e, incluso, podemos ayudarlas aportando [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Ejercicio: ¿A qué tipos abstractos corresponden los objetos `Range`? Iterable, Iterator, Sequence, Mapping,...

Hint: `dir(range)`